# How to create Photo wrap application in iPhone

Tags: android, iphone, ios, ipad

how can we create Photo Warp feature in iPhone application..

Similar applications already exist in android like [this](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=hu.tonuzaba.android), [this](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=hu.tonuzaba.photowarp2) and [this](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mixaimaging.deformerfree)

Please suggests if any.. thanks.

Comment: Open Xcode, create new project and get first any error bro. sorry for rude comment .. but without code how we can help you ??

Comment: You are looking for the complete code or XCODE project from the audience.

Comment: no, if any idea or small part will also helpful..